# remove lines in file from stream

Tags: ruby, bash

```
cat file_a
aaa
bbb
ccc

cat file_b
ddd
eee
fff

cat file_x
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

I want to `cat file_a file_b | remove_from_stream_what_is_in(file_x)`

Result:

```
aaa
fff
```

If there is no basic filter to do this with, then I wonder if there is a way with `ruby -ne '...'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ cat file_a file_b | grep -vFf file_x
aaa
fff
```

`-v` means remove matching lines.

`-F` tells grep to treat the match patterns as fixed strings, not regular expressions.

`-f file_x` tells grep to get the match patterns from the lines of `file_x`.

Other options that you may want to consider are:

`-w` tells grep to match only complete words.

`-x` tells grep to match only complete lines.

Comment: you frick'n genius! I hoped, thought, and believed there should be a way!

Comment: If the results are needed from within a Ruby program: `arr = \`cat file_a file_b | grep -vFf file_x\`.split("\n") #=> ["aaa", "fff"]`. Note that I had to escape the backticks for them to show in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
IO.write('file_a', %w| aaa bbb ccc |.join("\n"))     #=> 11
IO.write('file_b', %w| ddd eee fff |.join("\n"))     #=> 11
IO.write('file_x', %w| bbb ccc ddd eee |.join("\n")) #=> 15
```

From Ruby:

```
IO.readlines('file_a', chomp: true) + IO.readlines('file_b', chomp: true) -
  IO.readlines('file_x', chomp: true)
  #=> ["aaa", "fff"]
```

Comment: That is an incredibly fast (highly performant) solution. I am processing relatively large files... tens of thousands of lines each. This Ruby solution (`IO.readlines +/-`) took less than a second (0.2s), whereas the pipeline-equivalent (`| grep -vFf`) took more than 5 minutes on the same data. Thank you!

Comment: I am both surprised by your findings and pleased to have  helped.